# Google Visualization API - not showing tooltip

Tags: html, css, google-visualization

I've created charts on Google Visualization API, looks great to me. I'm having one bit of a problem. I tried to show my charts under a  tag which goes like this:

```
 <body>
    <!--Div that will hold the charts-->
<div style="width:1080px; background-color:gray">
    <div id="chart_div" style="float:left;"></div>
     <div id="pie_div" style="float:left;"></div>
     <div id="pie_div2"style="float:left;"></div>
     <div id="pie_div3"></div>
</div>
  </body>
```

The problem is, when I hover my mouse over the first 3 charts (Line, Pie chart 1, Pie chart 2) It doesnt show a tooltip just like what it does in the last piechart.

Here's my screenshot:

[image]

I think it has something to do with the style that I wrote on the divs. Anyone can help me out so I can show out the tooltips back on my charts?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I already got the answer. I just added the float code on the last pie chart and alas! the tooltips came back.

```
<body>
    <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
<div style="width:1080px; background-color:gray">
    <div id="chart_div" style="float:left;"></div>
     <div id="pie_div" style="float:left;"></div>
     <div id="pie_div2"style="float:left;"></div>
     <div id="pie_div3"style="float:left;"></div>
</div>
  </body>
```